# Changing the icon of my java application

Tags: java, netbeans

for a simple Java Desktop Application I added a JFrame Form with the assistant of the NetBeans IDE. For this frame I want to change the icon in the title bar.
I tried to do so with the following code at the very end of the constructor in the generated View class:

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(iconUrl);
    this.getFrame().setIconImage(ii.getImage());
```

The String iconUrl is definitely correct, the object ii seems to be alright as far as I can judge from the variables overview in the debugger perspective.
However, the icon in the title bar does not change, it's still the default java icon.

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Image i = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/path/to/image"));
setIconImage(i);
```

Note that here `/` would represent your `src` directory

Comment: When I put this into my constructor, it says "Cannot find symbol: Class: Image". So, it doesn't know the class "Image". What's wrong?

Comment: This process is making loading of frame very slow

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Image i = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("signal/icm/gui/images/oconp.png")).getImage();
setIconImage(i);
```

Comment: Never use ClassLoader for accessing Non System Resources, always use getClass().getResource(stringPath); Watch for the line in this [Access to Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) document, "All class loaders will search for a resource first as a system resource, in a manner analogous to searcing for class files.".

Answer (score 0):

Hope following solution works for you:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(IconURL);  
myImg = ImageIcon.getImage();   
JFrame.setIconImage(myImg);
```