# how to show login page in taskbar in netbeans platform

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I try to implementing a login page by using [this tutorial](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/60/nbm-login.html).

```
NotifyDescriptor nd = new NotifyDescriptor.Message("Ok");
DialogDisplayer.getDefault().notifyLater(nd);
```

But when the login screen is displayed, the application icon not showing in Taskbar. How i can resolve this problem?
Tnx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the icon of my java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327990/changing-the-icon-of-my-java-application)

Comment: This may also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209812/how-do-i-change-the-default-application-icon-in-java